# What all problems with broker or network can be detected using Transport Listener?

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

What all problems with broker or network can be detected using Transport Listener?

I am using failover uri with master/slave architecture. I want my clients to get notify if there is any problem with connection from client to broker. Though as soon as there will be problem with primary, failover will takeover and vice versa, but I want my client to know that there was some problem.

I know I can implement TransportListener and set it to my connection..but what all can be detected using TransportListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transport listener has events for connection interrupted and connection restored which would inform you client that the link between it and the broker has failed for some reason.  This doesn't necessary mean the broker went down as the network between the two could also be at fault but it is the only real indication you can get at the client level of such information.

Comment: is there a way to configure transport Listner using spring, I saw this [jira request AMQ-1434](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1434), if yes then how to configure it.

Comment: You set a transport listener instance on the ConnectionFactory that you configure your Spring stuff with.

Comment: How to know which broker has stopped, I want to print that whether primary has stopped or failover has stopped, how to go about it ?

Comment: Use other monitoring tools to do this or roll your own.

Comment: could you please suggest some of these tools?

Comment: Google can do that for you